# At least one fingerprint must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

When I try to run a sample app for fingerprint authentication, the following exception is thrown.

The devices I've tried are:

Samsung S5 (Android 6.0.1 API 23)

```
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one fingerprint must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:238)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi$AES.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:53)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:189)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp.authentication.VerificationActivity.generateKey(VerificationActivity.java:177)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp.authentication.VerificationActivity.initialize(VerificationActivity.java:131)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp.authentication.VerificationActivity.onCreate(VerificationActivity.java:63)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one fingerprint must be enrolled to create keys requiring user authentication for every use
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeymasterUtils.addUserAuthArgs(KeymasterUtils.java:115)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:234)
07-08 03:31:57.796 30558-30558/com.netfinitymedia.notubeapp W/System.err:   ... 17 more
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/18

Answer (score 3):

You should use the fingerprint manager to check if a fingerprint reader exists and if the app has permission to use it before trying to generate a key.

```
_fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) _context.getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

public boolean fingerprintEnabled()
{
    if (!_fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected())
    {
        // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication
        return false;
    }
    else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (!_keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (!_fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints())
    {
        // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#available), now with BiometricManager, we can use the [canAuthenticate](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricManager#canAuthenticate(int)) function to check if the authenticator meets the given requirements. Be careful with the combination of authentications types!

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL))
```

Comment: the condition still passes if user BIOMETRICS is ON but fingerprints list is empty.
approach doesn't work

Comment: If you want to use only BIOMETRICS login then you should remove DEVICE_CREDENTIAL from the if statement

when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG))

Then it will give you a BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED response

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround. I hope it will help you and other people outside:

```
Timber.d("checkForBiometrics started")
val fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(activity!!)
val pm = context!!.packageManager
val canAuthenticate: Boolean
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    val hasFingerprint = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)
    val hasFace = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE)
    val hasIris = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_IRIS)
    if(hasFingerprint && hasFace || hasFingerprint && hasIris) {
        Timber.d("checkForBiometrics has fingerprint and has face or iris")
        canAuthenticate = fingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
    } else if(hasFace || hasFingerprint) {
        Timber.d("checkForBiometrics has only face or only fingerprint")
        canAuthenticate = Biometric(activity!!).isAvailable()
    }
    else {
        canAuthenticate = false
    }
} else {
    canAuthenticate = false
}

return canAuthenticate
```

This will accept only fingerprint authentication, if device has more biometric options.